# How do i initialize the new version of crashlytics?

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Everything works fine when I initialize my application with:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

However, I get an exception when I use:

```
Fabric.with(this, new CrashlyticsCore());
```

The following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.weightbook, PID: 19438
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Crashlytics must be initialized by calling Fabric.with(Context) prior to calling Crashlytics.getInstance()
at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.checkInitialized(Crashlytics.java:372)
at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.setUserName(Crashlytics.java:248)
at com.weightbook.analytics.AnalyticsManager.setUsernameOnCrashlytics(AnalyticsManager.java:64)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mike from Fabric and Crashlytics here. Your first init call is correct, but you could also use:

```
Fabric.with(this, new CrashlyticsCore(), new Crashlytics());
```

or use:

```
Fabric.with(this, CrashlyticsCore.getInstance());
```

with the following imports:

```
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;
```

Using just `CrashlyticsCore.getInstance()` will give you only Crashlytics crash reporting and nothing else, where as `new Crashlytics()` would include Beta and Answers.

Comment: Thanks Miike!   So it appears that to use Crashlytics you need....new Crashlytics()  in there at least.   Thanks!! How is CrashlyticsCore different then?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're looking for. Clarified my answer.

Comment: Hi Mike i have suggested an edit use new CrashlyticsCore() instead of CrashlyticsCore.getInstance() because getInstance() method is accessing Fabric singleton object before it's initialisation and crashing the app on launch