# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must Initialize Fabric before using singleton()

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

I have found glitch in crashlytics/fabric initialization. As Mike from crashlytics suggests here: [how to initialize new fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294652/8187578) we should use:

```
Fabric.with(this, CrashlyticsCore.getInstance());
```

But when i switched to androidX it started crashing with:

> **Must Initialize Fabric before using singleton()**

Some of my main settings is:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 29
io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1
gradle: 5.5.1
com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0@aar
```

In onCreate in my Application class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, CrashlyticsCore.getInstance());
}
```

Of course i have metadata in manifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="myKey"/>
```

Comment: Your application is added in Manifest?

Comment: @FlorescuCătălin yes.

Answer (score 1):

This initialization works like a charm without any problems.

```
Fabric.with(this, new CrashlyticsCore(), new Crashlytics());
```

But i dont understand why the newer fails.

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't register your app in manifest file, Try this:

In your **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...
    />
```

And try initializing like this:

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        val core = CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(false).build()
        Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build())
    }
}
```

This is what I use in my projects and it works perfectly!

Comment: My application class is added in manifest. Glitch is that one implementation works and second one does not.

Comment: Maybe you should try initializing like this: Check my updated answer. @KebabKrabby

Comment: Thats outdated initialization according to link in the description.

Answer (score 1):

Mike's answer is incorrect from that link. 
When you use below initialisation

```
Fabric.with(this, CrashlyticsCore.getInstance());
```

`CrashlyticsCore.getInstance()` this getInstance method is trying to access Fabric class object which hasn't been created. Fabric object is created in `with` method which will be called once `CrashlyticsCore.getInstance()`is executed

Solution :

You can use any of below lines for initialisation since they're creating all objects using **new** keyword

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
Fabric.with(this, new CrashlyticsCore());
Fabric.with(this, new CrashlyticsCore(), new Crashlytics())
```